# does angular 2+ have full ie9 support for apps created with the cli?

Tags: angular

Does Angular 2+ have full IE9 support for apps created with the CLI?  Apps created with the CLI have a polyfills file with comments instructing to uncomment certain lines for IE9.  Will uncommenting these lines provide full polyfill support for IE9 or are additional polyfills potentially needed?

Answer (score 1):

Angular requires ES6 and you have to use a polyfill on browsers that don't support that version of JavaScript, and IE9 requires the polyfill.

Angular is a framework and to run that framework you need those polyfills, but it has a large ecosystem of add-on modules maintained by other developers. You can to verify each extra module you use to maintain IE9 compatibility.

If you build your app using a vanilla install of Angular without third-party modules, then the Angular team claims it is compatible.

Answer (score 0):

Look at [browser support](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/browser-support.html)  it depends what you are going to do you will need different set of polyfills